# External url is not working in PHP

Tags: string, wordpress, url, hyperlink, external

I was wondering if anyone knew how to solve this.
Im using wordpress.

I wanted to show the full url on a page.
My code is like this:

```
<p><?php echo '<a href="'.$url.'" title="'.$work->post_title.'" target="blank">'.__($url, "").'</a>'  ?> </p>
```

You can see the url but when you click on it you’ll get redirected to http://**Myownwebsite**.com/**THE_URL**

The problem is the “myownwebsite.com” part, how can I get rid of it?
I’ve also tried

```
<p><?php echo '<a href="'.$url.'"> '.$url.' </a>' ?> </p>
```

Any help ?

PS:
Adding RewriteRule ^links$ %{QUERY_STRING} [L,R=301] to .htaccess doesn't help.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the value of $url?

Comment: I have solved it, I had to use http:// instead of www. But I can't close this down, I have to wait 8 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.
I have to use [http://www.] for $url instead of [www]
I wanted to post this earlier, but stackoverflow didn't let me edit it for 8 hours.